Read JSON in Azure Data Factory
I am trying to configure the mapping section of the Copy data element to read from a REST endpoint. The REST returns JSON in the following way. How can I configure the mapping section? Please help!!
thanks


sorry forgot to mention - I need only the elements highlighted and not all the elements

Follow the below steps in the mapping to achieve your requirement.
First import the mapping -> Advanced Editor -> select areas-of-service array in the collection reference -> select unwanted columns -> Delete. Give necessary names to the required columns.

The mapping will look like this after deleting unwanted columns.

Debug the pipeline and it will the expected JSON like below.

